# Calculating total possibilities

Tags: probability

I wrote a random 3D transformation generator for a software program and I'm curious (for curiosity sake) how many possibilities it produces.

```
transform3D = CATransform3DRotate(transform3D, CGFloat(Double.pi) / CGFloat(randomDenominator), CGFloat(randomX), CGFloat(randomY), CGFloat(randomZ))
```

The code above takes 4 random parameters. The first parameter has 6 possible values, the second parameters has 6 possible values, the third parameter has 11 possible values, and the fourth parameter has 21 possible values.

How many possible combinations can this code produce?

Comment: *Sure you're joking, mister Feynman.* Are you really asking how to compute $6\cdot 6\cdot 11\cdot 21$ through a completely irrelevant context?

Answer (score 2):

The [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) says there are $6\cdot 6 \cdot 11 \cdot 21=8316$.  This will be reduced if there are different quadruples of parameters that can produce the same transform.

Comment: It was that easy, huh? Lol